# Unresolved dependency with specs2 scalaz-stream 0.5a

Tags: scala, sbt, scalaz, specs2

Since adding:

```
"org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.4.15" % "test" withSources() withJavadoc(),
```

To my build file I get

```
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.scalaz.stream:scalaz-stream_2.10:0.5a
[warn]        +- org.specs2:specs2_2.10:2.4.15
...
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalaz.stream#scalaz-stream_2.10;0.5a: not found
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding Scalaz repository should help

```
resolvers += "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

**upd** use *https*

Comment: You should never ever ever set "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases" in your build. It opens you up to cross build injection attacks. Only use https to add a repository to your build.